# ¿Cómo obtener TODOS los productos de una api paginada con phyton?

Tags: python, api, scraping

Tengo un problema en un ejercicio de consumo de api con Phyton.

El código me funciona, pero solo me trae un determinado numero de registros, dado que la api tiene los registros paginados (es decir en X número por páginas) por lo cual solo obtengo los resultados de la primera página.

Con este código obtengo la conexión a la api y me trae los resultados de la primer página (son 50 paginas en total según documenta la propia api), pero no se como seguir con la segunda y siguientes páginas:

```
#Librerias Consumo de Api
from requests import get
import json
import requests

#URL Consumo API Knasta  https://knasta.cl/api/results?q=notebook&page=2
producto = 'notebook'
api_url = f'https://knasta.cl/api/results?q={producto}'

#Librerias Scrapping
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
print("Importando Librerias para consumo de API y Web Scrapping")
print("Estableciendo Conexion con API KNASTA")

results_api = requests.get(api_url).json()['products']

results_api
```

Estoy haciendo pruebas con un while:

```
page = 0
params = {'num_pag': page}  

pages_remaining = True
full_res = []

while page <= 50:
    
    results_api = requests.get(api_url, params=params).json()['products']
        #results_api_retail = requests.get(api_url_retail).json()['products']
         
    print('Obteniendo Datos desde la API...')
        #Creamos el DataFrame
    df_retail = pd.DataFrame(results_api, columns = ['kid', 'product_id', 'title', 'kategory','retail'])
    page= page+1
    print(results_api)
```

Pero al momento de querer generar un DataFrame el mismo no se genera y aparece esto: __

Quedo atento a sus comentarios, saludos a todos

Comment: estas haciendo una doble importación de `get` (contenido en requests) y luego vuelves a importar requests, no es una muy buena practica

Comment: Esto sería más bien un acceso a una API, no se puede decir que sea _web scraping_ a no ser que luego hagas algo más. Tendrás que ver en esa API cómo puedes averiguar cuántas páginas tiene el resultado a devolver y cómo ir accediendo a cada una (eg: añadiendo el parámetro `page=2` para la segunda página, etc).

Comment: ¿Por qué no te facilitas la vida? [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/)

Comment: Creo que la mejor opción sería usa Scrapy como comenta @AlbertoSiurob

Answer (score 1):

Por suerte la consulta te devuelve el número total de paginas. Puedes usar el bucle while para recorrer todas las paginas y guardar todos los datos en una lista. Puedes hacer algo como esto:

```py
#Librerias Consumo de Api
import json,random,time,random,requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#URL Consumo API Knasta  https://knasta.cl/api/results?q=notebook&page=2
producto = 'notebook'
pages=[]
index=1
total_pages= requests.get(f"https://knasta.cl/api/results?q={producto}&page={index}").json()["total_pages"]

while index<=total_pages:    
    results_api = requests.get(f"https://knasta.cl/api/results?q={producto}&page={index}").json()['products']
    print("Pagina: ",index)
    pages.append(results_api) 
    index+=1   
    time.sleep(random.randrange(5))

# Añade todos los productos en una sola lista
df_retail=[]
for page in pages:
    for i in page:
        df_retail.append(i)

print(pd.DataFrame(df_retail, columns = ['kid', 'product_id', 'title', 'kategory','retail']))
```

Comment: Hola, me imprime solo la primer pagina con productos jeje

Comment: Hola, Nicolas ¿Lo intentaste con el código que te pase? Acabo de comprobar y veo que me devuelve los productos de las diferentes paginas https://prnt.sc/1eezekm

Comment: error mio tenia mal una variable que cambie, de que manera se puede imprimir TODAS las paginas juntas en un DataFrame

Comment: Para imprimir todas las páginas juntas puedes crear una sola Lista con los productos. Ahí edite el código para que veas la forma de hacerlo

Comment: Por que creas un dataframe con cada resultado de la api? Además estas sobrescribiendo el valor en cada iteracuon por lo que siempre saldrá el último

Comment: Hola, Christian, lo de crear un dataframe en cada iteración lo copie de Nicolas en las pruebas que el estaba haciendo. Deje esa línea para que el haga lo que quiera con ella.

Comment: Ok, aun que sería bueno que explicaras que eso esta mal y cual es la forma correcta de hacerlo

Comment: Tienes razón, Christian, esa línea ya no hacia nada allí. Ahi edite el código y la elimine. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hay cosas que se pueden simplificar, pero la respuesta está bien  